# Подключение к серверу из внешней сети

Tags: c#, .net

Стартую сервер

```
Int32 port = 11111;
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.132");

TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

server.Start();

while (true)
{
     TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
}
```

Проверяю - порт открыт, при подключении в локальной сети все работает, а при подключении по внешнему IP клиент не может подключиться, просто сервер никак не реагирует (как подключения и не было), у клиента выдает, что сервер недоступен. Как это исправить?

Comment: IP пингуется? Порт на сервере расшарен? не режется брандмауэром?

Comment: Второе не понял, как это проверить?

Comment: Отключите брандмауэр на сервере, проверьте подключение, включите его обратно

Comment: Тоже самое при отключении

Comment: вы стартуете сервер на адресе для локальных сетей 192.168.* (эта сеть не доступна из вне), который скорее всего выдан роутером, а внешний адрес у вас другой. Вам нужно настроить port forwarding на роутере (и нужно будет подключаться на этот адрус, а роутер уже его перенаправит в локальную сеть)

Comment: eXit, не помогает. Но при открытия айпи:порта сервера в браузере, выдает сообщение ```Сайт IP не позволяет установить соединение.```